# Resolve Path recursively

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to solve the problem which goes like this -

Given a map of key-value mapping

```
["Intro",  "Hello My Name is %S% and I am x %Y old"]
["S", "Tom %N"]
["N", "Johnson"]
["Y", "Year"]
```

Now resolve a String
`Give Your %Intro %S`

I am struggling to know what would be the best and optimized way to solve this. I can think of simple recursion but I don't know if that is the best way. I am also struggling to understand time complexity of a problem. Please note this can go to any depth.

What I did

```
 String resolve(String s, HashMap<String, String> m) {
        String[] st = s.split(" ");
        for(String word : st) {
            if(m.get(word) != null) {
                word = m.get(word);
            }
            if(word.contains("%")) {
                String p = resolve(parse(word), m);
                m.put(word, p);
            }
        }

        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        for(String word : st) {
            if(st.contains("%")) {
                b.append(m.get(word) + " ");
            } else {
                b.append(word + " ");
            }
        }
        return b.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Is there a problem with your method?

Comment: I am not sure if this is efficient and also i could not understand the complexity of this

Comment: You could use a stack instead of recursion I suppose

Comment: You could also have a function that only goes down one level. Then you have a wrapper around it that calls it over and over again until no changes are done.

Comment: There's a "simple" way to solve this and an "efficient" way to solve it (vs worst-case input), and several in-between ways to solve it.  Which is your goal?

Comment: i would like to know what is efficient way (from time complexity point of view)

Comment: Also, it is not always possible to correctly resolve all input sets according to your rules so far.  For instance, `["1", "ping %2 "]  ["2", "pong %1 "]` with starting string of `"%1"` cannot be resolved.

Comment: The efficient ways are pretty complicated, especially if they have to deal with possible cycles and other pathological input sets like my ping-pong example above.

Comment: Also, you cannot assign a finite complexity to any method that may not terminate.  As of now, the possibility of cycles in the input set means there is no possible algorithm that will always terminate.

Comment: lets skip cycle case for now.. do you know if a similar algorithm exist?

Comment: What exactly does your parse method do? What is `ss`? Or `kk`?

Comment: I changed the code

Comment: I think it's confusing to use `m` for both input and memoisation of resolved strings. I would add a third parameter to the function, which initially is an empty hashmap. Each time when you come across a word starting with `%` you check the map to see if you have resolved that already. If so, use the memoised result. Otherwise, recursively resolve the string and store it in the map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a lot of expressions and dependencies and you must to update and get values frequently you need a [**dependency graph**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_graph)

(For simplicity a variable is declared as `"My %var% is ..."` not `"My %var is ..."`)

Let the next `Var` class containing a variable (your `[name, expr]`)

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
static class Var {
    String name;
    String[] parts; // Const1,  Var1, Const2,   Var2, ...
                    // Hello... `S`   and I am  `Y`   old ...
    String computed;

    Stream<String> getUsedVarNames() {
        // we are interested only in Var# not Const# then
        // we traverse the odd indexes
        return IntStream
           // for i=1,2,3,...,N/2-1
           .range(1, parts.length / 2)
           // get the var `2*i-1` that is 1,3,5,...
           .mapToObj(i -> parts[2 * i - 1]);
    }

    void updateValue(Map<String, Var> vars) {
        System.out.println("          Computing: " + name);
        // update the value is concat all
        //    Const1 + Var1 + Const2 + Var2, ...
        // then
        computed = IntStream
                // for i=0,1,2,...,N-1
                .range(0, parts.length)
                // if is even (i%2==0) take the Const-i
                // if is odd           take the Var-i value
                .mapToObj(i -> i % 2 == 0 ? parts[i] : vars.get(parts[i]).getComputed())
                // and concatenate all
                .collect(joining());
    }
}
```

where

- `name` is the var name `S`, `N`, ...
- `parts` are the constants `"Hello My..."` in positions 0, 2, 4, ... and variable names `"S"` in positions 1, 3, 5, ... (for simplicity)
- `computed` is the last computed value
- `getUsedVarNames` get the used var names (1, 3, 5, ... positions)
- `updateValue` recompute the `computed` value given a map of vars.

then, a **basic** dependency graph management is basically

```
static class Graph {
    Map<String, Var> vars = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Set<String>> deps = new HashMap<>();

    String value(String name) {
        return vars.get(name).getComputed();
    }

    String add(String name, String expr) {
        remove(name);

        Var current = new Var(name, expr.split("%"), null);

        // add current dependencies
        current.getUsedVarNames().forEach(dep -> deps.get(dep).add(name));

        // add var
        vars.put(name, current);
        if(!deps.containsKey(name))
            deps.put(name, new HashSet<>());

        // compute
        updateDeps(name);

        return current.getComputed();
    }

    private void updateDeps(String name) {
        vars.get(name).updateValue(vars);
        deps.get(name).forEach(this::updateDeps);
    }

    void remove(String name) {
        if (vars.containsKey(name)) {
            vars.get(name).getUsedVarNames().forEach(dep -> deps.get(dep).remove(name));
            vars.remove(name);
        }
    }
}
```

where

- `vars` the `varName` => `the var`.
- `deps` map `parentVars` => `where are used`.
- `value` simply get the computed value for a var name.
- `add` remove the var if exists and set dependencies.
- `updateDeps` walk the `deps` graph updating dependencies.
- `remove` remove var and dependencies.

then, as an example you can write

```
Graph g = new Graph();

System.out.println(g.add("Y", "Year"));
System.out.println(g.add("N", "Johnson"));
System.out.println(g.add("S", "Tom %N%"));
System.out.println(g.add("Intro", "Hello My Name is %S% and I am x %Y% old"));

// if you change `S` only two expression are recomputed (the updated `S` and their dependencies)
System.out.println(g.add("S", "Peter %N%"));

System.out.println(g.value("Intro"));
```

with output

```
          Computing: Y
Year
          Computing: N
Johnson
          Computing: S
Tom Johnson
          Computing: Intro
Hello My Name is Tom Johnson and I am x Year old
          Computing: S
          Computing: Intro
Peter Johnson
Hello My Name is Peter Johnson and I am x Year old
```

where only required expressions will be recomputed.

**This is a very basic Dependency Graph management** (i.e. if a var not exists you get a null)

(Aside, full example code)

```
package com.computermind.sandbox.algorithms;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;

public class DependencyGraph {

    public static void main(String... args) {

    Graph g = new Graph();

    System.out.println(g.add("Y", "Year"));
    System.out.println(g.add("N", "Johnson"));
    System.out.println(g.add("S", "Tom %N%"));
    System.out.println(g.add("Intro", "Hello My Name is %S% and I am x %Y% old"));

    // if you change `S` only two expression are recomputed (the updated `S` and their dependencies)
    System.out.println(g.add("S", "Peter %N%"));

    System.out.println(g.value("Intro"));

    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    static class Var {
        String name;
        String[] parts;
        String computed;

        Stream<String> getUsedVarNames() {
            return IntStream.range(1, parts.length / 2).mapToObj(i -> parts[2 * i - 1]);
        }

        void updateValue(Map<String, Var> vars) {
            System.out.println("          Computing: " + name);
            computed = IntStream.range(0, parts.length)
                    .mapToObj(i -> i % 2 == 0 ? parts[i] : vars.get(parts[i]).getComputed())
                    .collect(joining());
        }
    }

    static class Graph {
        Map<String, Var> vars = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Set<String>> deps = new HashMap<>();

        String value(String name) {
            System.out.println("          Computing: " + name);
            return vars.get(name).getComputed();
        }

        String add(String name, String expr) {
            remove(name);

            Var current = new Var(name, expr.split("%"), null);

            // add current dependencies
            current.getUsedVarNames().forEach(dep -> deps.get(dep).add(name));

            // add var
            vars.put(name, current);
            if(!deps.containsKey(name))
                deps.put(name, new HashSet<>());

            // compute
            updateDeps(name);

            return current.getComputed();
        }

        private void updateDeps(String name) {
            vars.get(name).updateValue(vars);
            deps.get(name).forEach(this::updateDeps);
        }

        void remove(String name) {
            // remove current dependencies
            if (vars.containsKey(name)) {
                vars.get(name).getUsedVarNames().forEach(dep -> deps.get(dep).remove(name));
                vars.remove(name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer. looks very promising but find it hard to understand what getUsedVarNames & updateValue is doing. could you be kind to explain it

Comment: It might be wise to check that the graph is a DAG to avoid an infinite loop.

Comment: @Learner That's where seemingly boring theoretical computer science courses come in handy. Many problems map to graph theory and have existing algorithms to solve them.

Comment: @Tarik exactly, both loops (i.e. track visited nodes on `updateDeps` to check loop) and var not found (on every `.get`) should be implemented but I avoid that for simplicity.